# Copying a file to sharepoint through SAS unix

Tags: unix, sas

As a part of my work I need to create few reports in SAS and export them to sharepoint site. I am trying to automate this process as shown below.

```
call system ("cp -p file.xls https//sharepointsite/folder1/file.xls");
```

when i run this code, it is not giving any error in the code but the file not uploaded into sharepoint.

Could anyone suggest me the solution for this case.

Comment: Does that command work when run directly from the command line?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following in order to extract any errors into your log

```
data _null_;
  infile "cp -p file.xls https//sharepointsite/folder1/file.xls" pipe;
  input;
  list;
run;
```

You can also try running the command directly from your SAS server, as a shell command.  If that is successful, the above should be succesful (although I wasn't aware that uploading files to sharepoint was that straightforward).

**Edit:**  from reading around, I think it IS possible, you just need to have your sharepoint location mapped to a local directory, and to have contributor rights on the site itself.  In which case make sure you use the 'local' path for the URL..